# smtp;551 Mailhost is on domain's block list

Tags: iis, iis-7, smtp

We have a website hosted on Windows 2008 (SP2), running iis 7.0

One of the pages on our website, when submitted, will send an informational email to info@mywebdomain.com.  The email is sent to the localhost smtp server on the same server that the website runs on.  This had been working until December 10th and now it always fails.

As best I can tell, it looks like I need to remove mywebdomain.com from the smtp server's domain block list.  However, I cannot figure out how to do that.  I got as far as figuring out that the smtp server running under iis 7.0 is actually configured via the iis 6.0 manager.  I expanded "local computer", right-clicked "SMTP Virtual Server #1" (the only one in the list) and selected Properties.  I didn't see anything in any of the tabs which looked like it could be used to unblock a domain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!  Details below:

```
mywebdomain - substituted to keep this posting hopefully anonymous; but this domain is hosted on our server and is available on the internet

mwd3.mwd.local - again substituted for anonymity; but this is effectively localhost

From: postmaster@mwd3.mwd.local
To: webadmin@mywebdomain.com
Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2012 11:29:29 -0600
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
    boundary="9B095B5ADSN=_01CDCE88DCFE2F9B00000001mwd3.mwd.local"
X-DSNContext: 7ce717b1 - 1196 - 00000002 - 00000000
Message-ID: <f69aZbLAX00000001@mwd3.mwd.local>
Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)

This is a MIME-formatted message.  
Portions of this message may be unreadable without a MIME-capable mail program.

--9B095B5ADSN=_01CDCE88DCFE2F9B00000001mwd3.mwd.local
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=unicode-1-1-utf-7

This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

Delivery to the following recipients failed.

       info@mywebdomain.com

--9B095B5ADSN=_01CDCE88DCFE2F9B00000001mwd3.mwd.local
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns;mwd3.mwd.local
Received-From-MTA: dns;mwd3.mwd.local
Arrival-Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2012 11:29:25 -0600

Final-Recipient: rfc822;info@mywebdomain.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.5.0
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;551 Mailhost is on domain's block list (Mode: normal)

--9B095B5ADSN=_01CDCE88DCFE2F9B00000001mwd3.mwd.local
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Received: from mwd3.mwd.local ([127.0.0.1]) by mwd3.mwd.local with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.0.6002.18222);
     Mon, 10 Dec 2012 11:29:25 -0600
From: <webadmin@mywebdomain.com>
To: info@mywebdomain.com
Subject: Consumer Q & A
Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2012 11:29:25 -0600
Message-ID: <20121210-11292530-342c@mwd3.mwd.local>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Return-Path: webadmin@mywebdomain.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 10 Dec 2012 17:29:25.0305 (UTC) FILETIME=[E6549290:01CDD6FB]

The following information was submitted at 12/10/2012 11:29:25 AM from Consumer Q&A.

Body of the email
```

Comment: Since your MTA doesn't quite include enough information in the DSN message to be of much use, it would be helpful if you posted a transcript of an SMTP session showing the failure (edited if you wish, but what's the point? -- it would be more helpful to be repeatable elsewhere!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gregg,

Thanks for your comment.  I marked it as adding something useful to the post, since it wasn't an answer.

It took me a while to figure out how to get an SMTP transcript.

For others reading this post, here is how I did it.  Adapt it to your own situation.  I was able to stop/start the Virtual SMTP Server because the client gave me permission since it wasn't accomplishing the purpose it was setup for anyway.

Again, note that IIS 6 is used to administer the SMTP server even when you're running IIS 7.

1. Open up "Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager
2. I found instructions in the Help menu to enable logging:

   ```
   To enable logging that uses an ASCII text format
   ... Select the SMTP virtual server, and then click Properties on the Action menu. 

   On the General tab, select Enable logging. 

   In the Active log format drop-down menu, select a log format. 

   Click Properties, and then on the General tab, specify the New log schedule. 

   If you select Hourly, Daily, Weekly, or Monthly, a new log file is created at those intervals. 

   If you select Unlimited file size, only a single log file is created. 

   If you select When file size reaches, you can specify the maximum size of the log file and a new log file is created when the current log file reaches that size. 

   On the General tab, under Log file directory, specify the location where the log files will be stored. 

   If you have selected the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) Extended Logging format, click the Advanced tab, and then select the extended logging options you want to track.
   ```
3. I set my logging destination to a new folder just to be sure it wouldn't get mixed up with other logging.
4. I turned on every option in the Advanced tab.  Then I stopped and started the virtual server.
5. I sent an email using one of the website features which hadn't been working (Request Info)
6. When I tried to view the log, it said it was in use.  So I stopped the Virtual SMTP Server, copied the contents of the log, and then started the Virtual SMTP Server again.

Effectively what I discovered is that the client was using mxlogic.net for spam filtering.  He regularly contacts them when spam gets through their service.  I suspect when he contacted them on December 10th they blocked his address instead of the offending spammer.  But that is just speculation.

They acknowledged that his IP address was in a blocked IP range.  They fixed it within a few minutes and the problem is now resolved.

You can see below in the transcript that the first OutboundConnectionResponse is initiating a conversation with an mxlogic.net server.  The last line is a closing of the transmission channel with the mxlogic.net server.  In between you can see a couple of messages stating, "551+Mailhost+is+on+domain's+block+list"

```
    #Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.0
    #Version: 1.0
    #Date: 2013-01-03 17:29:41
    #Fields: date time c-ip cs-username s-sitename s-computername s-ip s-port cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query sc-status sc-

    win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken cs-version cs-host cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) 
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 127.0.0.1 mwd3.mwd.local SMTPSVC1 MWD3 127.0.0.1 0 HELO -         +mwd3.mwd.local 250 0 38 19 0 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 127.0.0.1 mwd3.mwd.local SMTPSVC1 MWD3 127.0.0.1 0 MAIL -         +FROM:+<webadmin@mywebdomain.com> 250 0 45 33 0 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 127.0.0.1 mwd3.mwd.local SMTPSVC1 MWD3 127.0.0.1 0 RCPT -         +TO:+<info@mywebdomain.com> 250 0 29 27 0 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 127.0.0.1 mwd3.mwd.local SMTPSVC1 MWD3 127.0.0.1 0 DATA - +<20130103-11294182-2d84@mwd3.mwd.local> 250 0 123 456 63 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 127.0.0.1 mwd3.mwd.local SMTPSVC1 MWD3 127.0.0.1 0 QUIT - mwd3.mwd.local 240 78 63 4 0 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 - - 220+p02c12m113.mxlogic.net+ESMTP+mxl_mta-6.16.0-0+[4d461940.13484498.00-2360];+Thu,+03+Jan+2013+10:29:41+-0700+(MST);+NO+UCE,+INBOUND 0 0 133 0 47 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 EHLO - mwd3.mwd.local 0 0 4 0 47 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 - - 250-p02c12m113.mxlogic.net 0 0 26 0 63 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 MAIL - FROM:<webadmin@mywebdomain.com> 0 0 4 0 63 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 - - 250+Sender+Ok 0 0 13 0 94 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 RCPT - TO:<info@mywebdomain.com> 0 0 4 0 94 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 - - 551+Mailhost+is+on+domain's+block+list+(Mode:+normal) 0 0 53 0 188 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 RSET - - 0 0 4 0 188 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 - - 250+Reset+Ok 0 0 12 0 219 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 RSET - - 0 0 4 0 266 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 - - 250+Reset+Ok 0 0 12 0 297 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 MAIL - FROM:<> 0 0 4 0 297 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 - - 250+Sender+Ok 0 0 13 0 312 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 RCPT - TO:<webadmin@mywebdomain.com> 0 0 4 0 312 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 - - 551+Mailhost+is+on+domain's+block+list+(Mode:+normal) 0 0 53 0 406 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 RSET - - 0 0 4 0 406 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 - - 250+Reset+Ok 0 0 12 0 422 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 QUIT - - 0 0 4 0 437 SMTP - - - -
    2013-01-03 17:29:41 208.65.145.12 OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 MWD3 - 25 - - 221+p02c12m113.mxlogic.net+Service+closing+transmission+channel+[13484498.00] 0 0 77 0 453 SMTP - - - -
```